# PHP - PostgreSQL error updating table

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-update, syntax-error

I fetch some values from a database and display them on some textfields. When I change one specific value and try to store it back to the database, it's done properly. But when I try to do the same with any other value from any other textfield, I get the error "syntax error at or near where". Any thoughts?

```
'UPDATE table1 SET "intcolumn"='. $value .', "stringcolumn"=\''.  $value2.'\''.' WHERE "column2"='.$value3);
```

Update on intcolumn is done properly. On stringcolumn I get the error, even if I update only stringcolumn

Comment: Use prepared statements and the problem will go away. `echo`ing the query will make the error easy to spot. Also, you are open to SQL injections

Comment: I know about SQL injection. I'm not concerned with it right now. Thanks. I'll try ti

Comment: BE concerned with SQL injection because you don't know how to escape values properly. It's fiddly and error-prone to do it yourself which is why almost every person who sees this sort of code says to use prepared statements.

Comment: Yes I know. I meant right now the page is offline and under development and there are other priorities. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Changing your apostrophes to quotes and putting your values inside delimiters will help readability.
This should make debugging easier, and easier to spot rather than having to escape characters etc.

```
pg_query($db, "UPDATE table1 SET intcolumn={$value}, stringcolumn='{$value2}' WHERE column2={$value3}");
```

A better approach would be to use pg_query_params and let postgres worry about escaping characters, and will stop injection attacks.

```
$params = array($value, $value2, $value3);
pg_query_params($db, "UPDATE table1 SET intcolumn=$1, stringcolumn=$2 WHERE column2=$3", $params);
```